# tfs check-out in different folders at once

Tags: tfs, out

I have the same files in multiple folders but with different descriptions(one folder for French, one for English).
If I do some changes in one folder, I have to check out also for the other folder the same files and do the same changes.
Is there a way to check out any of these files, and in the same operation to check out it's equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

No. There's nothing like that provided by TFS out of the box.

That said, it wouldn't be hard to write a small powershell script or batch file that takes the name of the file you want to checkout as a parameter and calls `tf checkout` for that file in both the English and French folders.

You could also add it to Visual Studio as an External Tool and pass the Item File Name as the parameter so that you can call it from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file I wrote that checks out a file from multiple folders, copies the latest file to these folders and checks in the latest files.  Modify and use and you see fit

```
echo off
rem Batch file to copy latest template files from archive to c:\aia\addapt 3\template
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem
echo checking out all instances of common.dll from tfs
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDapt3Library\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDaptObserverComponent\CAddaptObserver\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDaptPrintComponent\CAddaptPrint\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\DriveComponent\CDrive\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\FaultFifoComponent\CFaultFIFO\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\RealTimeComponent\AddaptRealTime\AddaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\SignalAnalyzerComponent\CSignalAnalyzer\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ViewModelComponent\CAddaptViewModel\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
rem
echo Need to define lastest location of common library
set /p CommonLib=Enter directory of common library:
set commonsrc=!CommonLib!\Common.dll
echo on
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDapt3Library\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDaptObserverComponent\CAddaptObserver\ADDaptLibrary\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDaptPrintComponent\CAddaptPrint\ADDaptLibrary\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\DriveComponent\CDrive\ADDaptLibrary\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\FaultFifoComponent\CFaultFIFO\ADDaptLibrary\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\RealTimeComponent\AddaptRealTime\AddaptLibrary\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\SignalAnalyzerComponent\CSignalAnalyzer\ADDaptLibrary\
copy /Y  %commonsrc% C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ViewModelComponent\CAddaptViewModel\ADDaptLibrary\
echo off
rem
echo checking in all instances of common.dll into tfs
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDapt3Library\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDaptObserverComponent\CAddaptObserver\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ADDaptPrintComponent\CAddaptPrint\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\DriveComponent\CDrive\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\FaultFifoComponent\CFaultFIFO\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\RealTimeComponent\AddaptRealTime\AddaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\SignalAnalyzerComponent\CSignalAnalyzer\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkin /noprompt /comment:"Latest common.dll assembly" C:\rd\ADDaptv3\ADDapt3\ViewModelComponent\CAddaptViewModel\ADDaptLibrary\common.dll
rem
set /p WAITONUSER=Enter return to continue
echo All done!
```